# adding class to position:sticky but is adding class to every sticky element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend, sticky

Added this code to my sticky element using position:sticky

```
var $sticky = $('.grid-container .sticky'),
  $stickyTo = $('.grid-container .stickyTo'),
  stickyToTop = $stickyTo.offset().top,
  stickyToBottom = stickyToTop + $stickyTo.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
    stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top,
    stickyBottom = $sticky.offset().top + $sticky.outerHeight();

  if (stickyBottom >= stickyToBottom) {
    if (scroll < stickyTop) {
      //$sticky.addClass('fixed').removeClass('abs');
    } else {
      //$sticky.addClass('abs');
    }
  } else if (scroll > stickyToTop) {
    $sticky.addClass('stuck');
  } else if (scroll < stickyToTop) {
    $sticky.removeClass('stuck');
  }
});
```

and I have two sticky elements see image attached but when I scroll to the first section it adds a class "stuck" on the second section, how can I make that only on that section jquery is triggered and not affect the second/other section unless scrolled on

[image]

Here is My [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5eq4nmhy/)

Comment: You are applying class 'stuck' to all the elements with the class 'sticky'.  If you want to apply it to only one element, give that elements an id.  And then use that id to add class to it.

Comment: well that is dynamic so it will have many sections so I will have many ID's as well?

Answer (score 1):

Because `$sticky` in your case is a jQuery collection with two elements in it you have to use `.each()` loop to check each element separately. Then you probably don't need `$stickyTo`, because you have to check for each 'sticky' element's own `.parent()`. Something like this:

```
var $sticky = $('.grid-container .sticky'),


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
  $sticky.each(function(){
    const $this = $(this) 
    const stickyTop = $this.offset().top,
    const stickyBottom = stickyTop + $sticky.outerHeight();

    const $stickyTo = $this.parent()
    const stickyToTop = $stickyTo.offset().top,
    const stickyToBottom = stickyToTop + $stickyTo.outerHeight();

    if (stickyBottom >= stickyToBottom) {
      if (scroll < stickyTop) {
        //$sticky.addClass('fixed').removeClass('abs');
      } else {
        //$sticky.addClass('abs');
      }
    } else if (scroll > stickyToTop) {
      $sticky.addClass('stuck');
    } else if (scroll < stickyToTop) {
      $sticky.removeClass('stuck');
    }
  })
});
```

Please note though, this function is not really optimized. It would be better to use native javascript during the scroll. Or even better check native [CSS `position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: Hello, here is my fiddle and I cant get it to work https://jsfiddle.net/5eq4nmhy/

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan. With `position: sticky` you don't need your javascript at all. And the `top` of the 'sticky' in your case should be 0. check this fiddle:  [https://jsfiddle.net/tyminko/xfz09ugq/12/](https://jsfiddle.net/tyminko/xfz09ugq/12/)